# deployment of spring boot and spring security in one project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have been given a spring boot JWT auth service and been asked to use it to secure a Restful web service I am currently building. Following  [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) tutorial I gathered that you can build multiple spring boot apps in one project. Specifically, the two modules *security* and *rest* each has an Application.java class to start the app. What I am not clear about is

1. Can I assume if the two apps started in the same server, calling the *rest controller* will be intercepted automatically by the security app to check for auth/authorise. If this is the case, then I assume no further code modification in the security or rest is needed?
2. I assume that each app in point 1 above can be started separately when deployed to a server, while in the IDE, both will get started at the same time?
3. What if I were to run on two separate servers, will the rest api calls need to be diverted to the security what is the architecture like, any examples would be appreciated?

Comment: I think you mixed some things up. If you have 2 applications, they are separate, no matter how they are deployed. Also, usually you don't have a module "security", because security will be a configuration of your application, not a separate module.

Comment: @dunni, in the spring io link, which points to their github project, they have rest folder with its own pom and another for security with its own pom, so it is telling me it is 2 separate modules.

Comment: These are 2 completely separate microservices. One is to provide the security stuff (which in your case would be the given JWT auth service), and the other one uses that to authenticate the users (the rest module, or in your case the restful web service). But i will try to provide an answer to your points.

Comment: so this suggests to me the architecture is micro services - it is the way forward. is this right?

Comment: It depends on your use case. Microservices are not suitable for everything. You have to decide if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. If you have two completely separate applications, a request to one application won't be intercepted by any code from the second application. If you want to have a security configuration in your REST service, you have to configure it for that. Spring Security provides the necessary mechanisms. The security app is there to hold the data for the authentication, like storing of usernames and passwords and providing a mechanism to check both. But if you want to secure endpoints of other applications, you have to configure those applications appropriately.
2. Not necessarily. If you want to run both applications in your IDE, you have to start both applications.
3. It really depends, what security mechanism you use. If you use e.g. OAuth, requests to a service either need already token which are then verified with the security service, or (in case of a web app with a GUI) would be redirected to the security service to sign in, and then redirected back to the web app with the token, which can then further be used.